# datagridview click event handle and open new form

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I'll trying to open another window to edit the datagridview datas.This is my code. please fix this error.
 project name is sms. datagridview name is `StudentsDataGridView`.

> Error BC30389 'sms.edit.idTextBox' is not accessible in this context
>   because it is 'Private'.

```
Private Sub StudentsDataGridView_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StudentsDataGridView.Click

    Dim editform As New edit

    editform.idTextBox.Text = StudentsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
    editform.TxtAdmNo.Text = StudentsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()

    editform.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest that you find a beginners tutorial and work your way through, paying particular attention to what the `Private` keyword means and what the alternatives are. We're here to help with actual problems rather than things that you aren't willing to look up in the documentation or a simple web search. SO is very much a place not to be spoon-fed.

Comment: Is the `edit` a custom class? Please, show its definishion.

Comment: form 2 is edit. this code is going on form1. datagridview is in form1. when the click on datagridview, i want to open edit form to edit the data

Comment: Error message is pretty clear - search it from the Web and you will get answers.

Comment: The `editform` object is an `edit` class instance. What is an `edit` definition? It is not class of standard assemblies, isn't it? I need to see `edit` type definition and definition of `idTextBox` property to help you. Could you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Modifier` property of the `edit` TextBox to `Public`.

But the right way is pass the argumnet to the edit window.

open the `edit` code, and add a constractor which receives parameters, then write the code for place the values in the desired controls:

```
Public Sub New(id As String, admNo As String)

    InitializeComponent()
    idTextBox.Text = id
    TxtAdmNo.Text = admNo
End Sub
```

now in caller code you can do:

```
Dim val_id = StudentsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
Dim adm = StudentsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()

Dim editform As New edit(val_id, adm)

editform.ShowDialog()
```

This way you separate the dependence between your software parts, and also requires you to provide the required data in creating the second form.

Comment: @ThiliniRathnayake i editedmy answer, and if my answer it helped you please indicate on mark it as `accept answer`

Comment: its a new question... StudentsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value its a date?